# Chained Promis in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am new to angular and I am struggling to see how I should create a particular promise. I am also using typescript for coding.

I need to call a web service to authenticate this has to be done in 2 steps.

**Step 1**

Request an authentication key

**Step 2**

Process logon details with authentication key and return to service to retrieve the logged on user or error if incorrect

So I have created an angular service called AuthenticationService
like below (this of course doesn't work)

```
  export class Authentication
    {
        $inject: string[] = ['$http'];

        public Authenticate( userName: string, password: string ): ng.IHttpPromise<ApiModel.ApiResult<ApiModel.AuthenticatedUser>>
        {
         $http.post( "/Account/AuthenticationKey", null )
            .then<ApiModel.ApiResult<string>>( result =>
            {
                var strKey = userName + password; //TODO: Put correct code here!

                var promiseToReturn = $http.post( "/Account/Authenticate", { key: strKey })
                    .then<ApiModel.ApiResult<ApiModel.AuthenticatedUser>>( result =>
                    {
                        return result;
                    });
            });
        }
    }
```

How do I go about returning a promise with the correct return type from the authentication method that returns the second result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you that in JavaScript as i am not conversant with typescript. The idea is to create your own promise and resolve it whenever you want. Basically

```
var autenticate=function(user,password) {
    var defer=$q.defer();
    $http.post( "/Account/AuthenticationKey", null )
      .then(function(data) {
         //do something on data
         $http.post( "/Account/Authenticate", { key: strKey })
           .then(function(result) {
              defer.resolve(result)
         });
      })
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: This has given me a bit of insight I am going to investigate a bit in typescript

Answer (score 1):

A `then` function should always either return another promise or a return value. The final `then` function should return a value which will get propagated to the top.

The relevant documentation can be found here : 
https://github.com/kriskowal/q

**NOTE :** Angular's promise implementation is based on kriskowal's q.

This is the relevant section of the documentation :

> If promiseMeSomething returns a promise that gets fulfilled later with
>   a return value, the first function (the fulfillment handler) will be
>   called with the value. However, if the promiseMeSomething function
>   gets rejected later by a thrown exception, the second function (the
>   rejection handler) will be called with the exception.

In your case, you should do something like

```
export class Authentication
{
    $inject: string[] = ['$http'];

    public Authenticate( userName: string, password: string ): ng.IHttpPromise<ApiModel.ApiResult<ApiModel.AuthenticatedUser>>
    {
     return $http.post( "/Account/AuthenticationKey", null )
        .then<ApiModel.ApiResult<string>>( result =>
        {
            var strKey = userName + password; //TODO: Put correct code here!

            return $http.post( "/Account/Authenticate", { key: strKey })
                .then<ApiModel.ApiResult<ApiModel.AuthenticatedUser>>( result =>
                {
                    return result;
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Notice the two returns before the `$http.posts` that you are calling. All `$http` methods in Angular return a promise, which means you dont need to explicitly create another promise.

Comment: The problem is the return needs to be a ApiModel.ApiResult<ApiModel.AuthenticatedUser> not a ApiModel.ApiResult<string>